# How to build sound card drivers?

Tags: drivers, make

I downloaded the drivers for my sound card (`XFiDrv_Linux_Public_US_1.00.tar.gz`) from a website. The readme file says:

> #### Quick install
>
> In terminal,
>
> 1. Goto source directory
> 2. Execute make command as root
>
>    make
>    make install

I'm not sure what it means. What exactly do I need to do?